# Dynamically adding resources to XCode project, always one cycle behind

Tags: xcode, ios, macos

I need to assemble resources for an application depeding on XCode build settings. The easiest way to achieve this, is through a build script phase. Although this works, this somehow always builds my target with resources one version lagging (a second build is needed to get things really up-to-date). 
The Resources folder is a reference to a folder in which my script (or rather, custom built command line tool called from script) copies the appropriate resources. The run script build phase is the first (topmost) phase in my target.

A solution I've found on the web somewhere, is to create an "External Target" and add that to the original target's build phases (by dragging the External target onto the original target). This does indeed seem to fix the "one version behind" issue, but I cannot seem to get the current target's environment variables to be passed to this "External target".

Why is XCode not including the just updated resources? What other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define an internal target (say, "ResourceTarget") and make the main target dependent on ResourceTarget. Then let your script run in the script build phase of ResourceTarget, so the resources are all updated when the second target is build.

That way, environment variables should be the same.